# Get Power Bi access token using angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Developing an app to embed Power bi dashboard using Angluar 6. The app is registered as Native app. Able to do Azure Active Directory authentication using `adal-angular4`. After authentication able to receive the `id_token`. Now with that token how to get the Power Bi 'access token' so that the dashboard can be embedded.

using the following config

```
adalConfig: {
  tenant: 'tenantId',
  clientId: 'clientId',
  loginResource: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
  postLougoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
}
```

Comment: You request an `access token` using either an `authorization code` or a `refresh token`. The `id_token` only gives you information about the end user. Nothing more. Try your search engine FU to research what you have to do...

Comment: Have set oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true in application Manifest file in Azure. It return the access token with that I was able to embed Power Bi.